# select languages using django get_available_languages

Tags: django

I have a portal language field i want dropbox to select the language.can we use django get_available_languages to implement this.

models.py

```
class OtherDetails(models.Model):

   portal_language = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

forms.py

```
class OtherDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
   widgets = {
        'portal_language': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('Portal language')}),
    }
```

template.html

```
{{ otherdetails_form.as_p }}
```

Answer (score 1):

put this in the templates

```
{% load i18n %}
<label>Portal Language:</label>
<select name="language" id="id_language">
    {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
    {% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
        <option>
            {{ lang.1 }}
        </option>
    {% end for %}
</select>
```

add these in the settings

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
  'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',

)
```